# Provisioning users in Azure Devops and creating tasks for them

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

We have a bulk import mechanism where we add users to ADO and create tasks assigned to them using the [user Entitlements API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/user%20entitlements/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0). We have observed that after initially adding the users to ADO, any tasks created for them via the [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) does not resolve the user's identity correctly. Any subsequent tasks are created correctly and show the users resolved.

Any task's '`Assigned To` field should be an `Identity` -

> Fname Lname alias@email.com

but for the first upload, it is just alias@email.com.

Is there a way to do this so that this works, even for first upload?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested it in my side and I can assign the new user for the work item by api.

And you should check if the new account has the right permission.

These are my json test:

```
[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.Title",
    "from": null,
    "value": "xxx"
  },

  {

    "op" : "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.AssignedTo",
    "from": null,
    "value": "xxx@outlook.com"
  }
]
```

I can use it under postman. Also, you could use the e-mail or user name under `value`.

**Besides**, you could share the used tool and the steps about your operation with us to help us troubleshoot your issue more quickly.